# Package versioning in Golang

Tags: go

I have a question about package versioning in Golang projects.

After creating a tag, for example `v1.0.0`.
I can pull this tag using `go get pkg_address/@v1.0.0` which is fine and works correctly.

But when I see Go packages in github I see that it's written in their installation section to install the package using `pkg_address/v1.0.0`.

In fact they are pulling a specific version without `@`.
And they even import packages in their code using `pkg_address/v1` even though there is no directory called `v1` in their project.

I get error if I install a specific tag without `@`.
Even after using `pkg_address/@v1.0.0` my import paths don't change and I don't need to specify version in my import paths.

For example you install echo package using this command `go get github.com/labstack/echo/v4` and you import the package using the `v4` tag in your code and there is no `v4` in the package directories.

How can I do versioning like github packages?

P.S. I'm using gitlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a module path naming convention and it applies to *major* versions higher than `v1`.

https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-path

> - If the module is released at *major* version **2 or higher**, the `module path` **MUST** end with a major version suffix like `/v2`. This may or may
>   not be part of the subdirectory name. For example, the module with
>   path golang.org/x/repo/sub/v2 could be in the /sub or /sub/v2
>   subdirectory of the repository golang.org/x/repo.

https://go.dev/ref/mod#major-version-suffixes

> Starting with major version 2, `module paths` **MUST** have a major
> version suffix like `/v2` that matches the major version. For example,
> if a module has the path example.com/mod at v1.0.0, it must have the
> path example.com/mod/v2 at version v2.0.0.

And echo's v4 `module path` can be found [here](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/da85d23/go.mod#L1).

Comment: Thank you so much, so it doesn't have to be in package directory. You just have to update the `module path`.